# Busco alternativas para la función .setActive();

Tags: javascript

Busco alternativas para dicha función ya que da problemas de compatibilidad con Chrome o Firefox.

```
this.mostrar = function() {
    selectedRow = 0;
    marco.getDiv().filters[0].Apply();
    marco.setZIndex(zIndex);
    this.quitScroll();
    if (parseInt(marco.getY()) + marco.getHeight() > document.body.offsetHeight) {
        if (((parseInt(marco.getY())) - ((parseInt(marco.getY()) + marco.getHeight()) - (document.body.offsetHeight - 4))) < 0) {
            this.makeScroll();
            this.setPosicion(parseInt(marco.getX()), 0);
        } else {
            this.setPosicion(parseInt(marco.getX()), ((parseInt(marco.getY())) - ((parseInt(marco.getY()) + marco.getHeight()) - (document.body.offsetHeight - 4))));
        }
    } else {
        this.setPosicion(parseInt(marco.getX()), parseInt(marco.getY()) - containerDiv.scrollTop);
    }
    if (parseInt(marco.getX()) < 0) {
        this.setPosicion(0, parseInt(marco.getY()));
    } else if (parseInt(marco.getX()) + marco.getWidth() > document.body.offsetWidth) {
        this.setPosicion(document.body.offsetWidth - marco.getWidth(), parseInt(marco.getY()));         
    }
    marco.mostrar();
    marco.getDiv().filters[0].Play();
    marco.getDiv().lastChild.style.width = marco.getDiv().offsetWidth + "px";

    containerDiv.setActive();

}
```

**Error en consola**:

> "Uncaught TypeError: div.setActive is not a function".

Comment: ¿De qué frameworks estamos hablando? ¿Cuál es tu código? Añade más información y contexto a tus preguntas, por favor.

Comment: ¿Y de que framework estamos hablando? ¿Es el API de Google Maps?

Comment: no, debe ser una función muy vieja de javascript

Comment: Sí, es un método deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/setActive Pregunta, ¿existe la posibilidad de eliminar el iframe? Supongo que no...

Comment: no es posible, en ese caso muchas gracias por la información.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar con el método [focus()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp)

```
let iframe = document.getElementById("i2");
iframe.contentWindow.focus();
console.log(document.activeElement.id);
iframe = document.getElementById("i1");
iframe.contentWindow.focus();
console.log(document.activeElement.id);
```

Te dejo un ejemplo [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/eudhxb6p/). He creado dos `iframes`, primero hago el foco en el `i1` y luego en el `i2` y verás que el elemento activo es primero uno y luego el otro.

Más [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995524/is-it-possible-to-change-document-activeelement-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)